# passar variável javascript para uma variável em php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Bom dia pessoal,

estou com uma dúvida:

eu tenho um select que pega o um array do banco, e toda vez que o user muda o select tem um change no javascript que atualizar isso em um input do tipo hidden >

```
<input id="id_clinic_hidden" hidden name="clinic_id">
```

a função javascript é essa:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#doc_sel_clinic", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $("#id_clinic_hidden").val(id);
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

O que quero fazer é pegar essa variável id do javascript para php, pode ser via sessão. 
Isso tá dentro do javascript pq preciso mudar o valor quando o usuário mudar o select.

obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo:

```
var myval = 'test';

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'seuphpfile.php',
  data: {'variable': myval},
});
```

Recebendo a variavel no PHP (`seuphpfile.php`)

```
$minhaVariavel = $_POST['variable'];
```

Comment: Olá, eu ainda não estou no notebook pra testar, porém isso atualiza a variável toda vez que que acontecer o evento do onchange?

Answer (score 2):

Para isso você irá precisar trabalhar com [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), o qual faz requisições **http** se forma assíncrona;

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'caminho_do_php_que_ira_recebe_o_input.php',
   dataType : 'html',
   type : 'POST',
   data : {'id' : id},
   beforeSend : function () {
         console.log('Carregando...');
   },
   success : function(retorno){
       console.log(retorno);
   },
   error : function(a,b,c){
       console.log('Erro: '+a[status]+' '+c);
   }
});
```

Basicamente é chamar em uma função (no momento que quiser enviar) e pronto, no lado do servidor, basta receber da seguinte maneira:

```
$valor_recebido = $_POST['id'];
```

Caso queria receber algum retorno após o envio com o `return` do **PHP**, basta receber e trabalhar com essa variável chamada `retorno` (caso achar melhor nomeie como preferir).

Comment: boa, para que serve esse dataType?

Comment: `dataType` é formado de resposta do servidor, eu particularmente só uso `html` ou `json`, mas não é um campo obrigatório.

Answer (score 0):

fiz dessa forma no javascript como vcs recomendaram:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "#doc_sel_clinic", function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#id_clinic_hidden").val(id);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: base_url + 'Doctor/config_schedule',
      data: {'id_selected': id},
    });

    console.log(id);
  });
```

e tentei buscar a no php>

```
<?php $minhaVariavel = $_POST['id_selected']; ?>
```

Porém não tive sucesso, retorna erro:

> ```
> Message: Undefined index: id_selected
> ```

Comment: você tem que testar para ver se ela existe exemplo:`<?php if(isset($_POST['id_selected'0) $minhaVariavel = $_POST['id_selected']; ?> `

Comment: sim, o isset não resolve meu problema, pq eu queria que fosse atualizada no evento do onchange como mostrei. A página ela mostra os dados conforme o que for escolhido nesse select, aí toda vez que o user escolher um select ele tem que atualizado. não tô conseguindo fazer isso.

Comment: eu não sei se estou passando o path de url do ajax corretamente, pq aqui usamos url amigavél e codeigniter, não sei se é isso.